# Angular2.0.0-rc1 async routers

Tags: angular

With latest changes from May 2016 (RC1) there is now **@Routes**, no more **@RouteConfig** where I could have used **newAsyncRoute** in order to async load the component.

The documentation is not yet ready at Angular.io, anybody knows how to use async router now with new routing, like in this case:

```
@Routes([
        { path: '/first', component: FirstComponent },
        { path: '/second', component: SecondComponent }
    ])
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This doesn't work in the new RC.3 router anymore. New ways for async routing seems to be on its way*

Something like

```
@Routes([
    { path: '/first', component: 'app.first.component.js' },
    { path: '/second', component: 'app.second.component.js' }
])
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8861 and https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8455/files (search for `@Routes`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Okay, so actually after I found this video from NG conference I figured it out...the point is that you put the component in quotes to break the dependency and then the system.js will load it afterwards: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8yAdeshpcw&index=9&list=PLOETEcp3DkCq788xapkP_OU-78jhTf68j